# Clearing the Matplotlib plot without clearing slider

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipywidgets

I'm currently creating an application where I need to update matplotlib graphs. I'm stuck at following step. 
I have a scatter plot and slider in the same figure. Upon changing the slider value, I need to clear the scatter plot without clearing the slider. Following is the code I implemented, but it does not clear the plot.
The `.clf()` function removes both the slider and scatter plot. Is there a way I could remove only the plot without impacting the slider?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


X1=np.arange(10)
Y1=np.arange(10)
Z1=np.arange(10)
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax=plt.scatter(X1,Y1,Z1)

axSlider1=plt.axes([0.3,0.9,0.3,0.05])
Slder2=Slider(ax=axSlider1,label='Slider',valmin=1,valmax=4,valinit=2)

plt.show()

# Function to clear the scatter plot without effecting slider.
def val_update(val):
    plt.cla()

Slder2.on_changed(val_update)
```

Comment: When I run it, nothing happens except the slider value/bar *in* the plot changes.

Comment: In your example `plt.show()`  needs to be the last statement for your symptom to be reproducible. Please read [mre].

Comment: Sorry. You are right. I have updated the question

Comment: Apologies for my mistake. I am new to this community. Still in learning phase.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Unfortunately, I have not yet reached the voting privilege for my upvote to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
```

Assigned the Axes object to `ax` - then

```
ax=plt.scatter(X1,Y1,Z1)
```

assigns a PathCollection object to `ax`. So `val_update` is tying to act on the wrong thing.

This seems to solve the issue you asked about.

```
X1=np.arange(10)
Y1=np.arange(10)
Z1=np.arange(10)
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
path=plt.scatter(X1,Y1,Z1)

axSlider1=plt.axes([0.3,0.9,0.3,0.05])
Slder2=Slider(ax=axSlider1,label='Slider',valmin=1,valmax=4,valinit=2)


# Function to clear the scatter plot without effecting slider.
def val_update(val):
    print(val)
    ax.clear()

Slder2.on_changed(val_update)

plt.show()
```

---

The [Matplotlib Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/index.html) is a good resource you can browse through it looking for features you want and see how they were made. - Like this [slider demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html)

If you think you will be using matplotlib in the future I would recommend working your way through the Introductory [tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/index.html) and at least the Artists tutorial

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helps.